# Using SQL Server image in Rancher?

Tags: sql-server, docker, rancher

I have a SQL Server Docker image that I am trying to deploy in a workload using Rancher. I am using the Rancher UI and just trying to perform a simple Deploy with the image. I keep getting the error:

> ReplicaSet “sqlserver-6f694b9b4b” has timed out progressing.; Deployment does not have minimum availability.

Please help me understand what the error is and how to resolve.

Comment: This sounds like one of those generic k8s errors that could be insufficient resources, failed readiness/liveness probes, or other pod startup failures. Any other messages in the pod's logs or anything that might help further troubleshoot?

Comment: What kind of logs are you looking for? I am very new to Rancher and I am just playing around with simple images and deployment. If you could guide me as to what kind of logs you are looking for, I can copy paste them here. Thanks.

Comment: There are no logs under pods at all. The pods are just marked Unavailable.